# Determine the cumulative probability distribution function of random variables $W = XY$ and $Z = X + Y$.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

The random variables $X$ and $Y$ are independent; $1 − P(X = 0) = P(X =1) = {1 \over 3}$ and $Y$ has Uniform distribution over the interval $[0, 2]$. Determine the cumulative probability distribution function of random variables $W = XY$ and $Z = X + Y$.

$X$ is a discrete random variable
$P(X=0) = {2 \over 3}$
$P(X=1) = {1 \over 3}$

$Y$ is a uniformly distributed random variable $Y$ ~ $[0,2]$, then:

$P(Y<y) = 0$ if $y<0$
$P(Y<y) = {y \over 2}$ if $0 \leq y \leq 2$ 
$P(Y<y) = 1$ if $y>2$

First, for $W=XY$

$P(W < w) = P(XY < w)$

Since X is discrete, we'll have to take every value separately

If $x=0$
$P(XY \leq w) = 0$ if $w < 0$
$P(XY \leq w) = {2 \over 3} \times {w \over 2} = {w \over 3}$ if $0 \leq w \leq 2$

If $x=1$
$P(XY \leq w) = 0$ if $w < 0$
$P(XY \leq w) = {1 \over 3} \times {w \over 2} = {w \over 6}$ if $0 \leq w \leq 2$

Now, combining, we'll get

$P(XY \leq w) = 0$ if $w < 0$
$P(XY \leq w) ={w \over 3}+ {w \over 6} = {w \over 2} $ if $0 \leq w \leq 2$
$P(XY \leq w) = 1$ if $w > 2$

Now, for $Z = X + Y$.

If $x=0$

$P(X+Y < w) = 0$ in $w < 0$ 
$P(X+Y < w) = {2 \over 3} + {w \over 2}$ if $0 \leq w \leq 2$

If $x=1$

$P(X+Y < w) = 0$ in $w < 0$ 
$P(X+Y < w) = {1 \over 3} + {w \over 2}$ if $0 \leq w \leq 2$

And finally, combining, we'll get

$P(X+Y < w) = 0$ in $w < 0$
$P(X+Y < w)= {2 \over 3} + {w \over 2} + {1 \over 3} + {w \over 2} = 1+w $ if $0 \leq w \leq 2$ #It doesn't look correct.
$P(XY \leq w) = 1$ if $w > 2$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $X \in \{0,1\}$, so irrespective of what $Y$ is, we must have $$W = XY = \begin{cases} 0, & X = 0 \\ Y, & X = 1. \end{cases}$$  So the CDF of the variable $W$ is, by the law of total probability,
$$\begin{align}
\Pr[W \le w] &= \Pr[XY \le w \mid X = 0]\Pr[X = 0] + \Pr[XY \le w \mid X = 1]\Pr[X = 1] \\
&= \Pr[0 \le w]\frac{2}{3} + \Pr[Y \le w]\frac{1}{3}. \tag{1} \end{align}$$  The first probability is simply $$\Pr[0 \le w] = \begin{cases}0, & w < 0 \\ 1, & w \ge 0. \end{cases} \tag{2}$$  The second probability is
$$\Pr[Y \le w] = \begin{cases}0, & w < 0 \\ w/2, & 0 \le w \le 2 \\ 1, & w > 2. \end{cases} \tag{3}$$  So the resulting CDF for $W$ is
$$\Pr[W \le w] = \begin{cases}0, & w < 0 \\
\frac{2}{3} + \frac{1}{3} \cdot \frac{w}{2}, & 0 \le w \le 2 \\
\frac{2}{3} + \frac{1}{3} \cdot 1, & w > 2 \end{cases}
= \begin{cases} 0, & w < 0 \\ \frac{w+4}{6}, & 0 \le w \le 2 \\ 1, & w > 2.
\end{cases} \tag{4}$$
Your answer cannot be correct because there is a discrete probability mass at $W = 0$, since $\Pr[W = 0] = \Pr[X = 0] = \frac{2}{3}$, and your CDF is continuous at $W = 0$.  Notice that the CDF in $(4)$ must use the bounds $0 \color{red}{\le} w \le 2$ in the second case, in order to correctly obtain $\Pr[W \le 0] = (0+4)/6 = 2/3$.

A similar solution method works for $Z = X+Y$.  We have $$Z = X+Y = \begin{cases}Y, & X = 0 \\ Y+1, & X = 1. \end{cases} \tag{5}$$  Again by the law of total probability,
$$\begin{align}
\Pr[Z \le z] &= \Pr[Z \le z \mid X = 0]\Pr[X = 0] + \Pr[Z \le z \mid X = 1]\Pr[X = 1] \\
&= \Pr[Y \le z]\frac{2}{3} + \Pr[Y+1 \le z]\frac{1}{3} \\
&= \frac{2}{3} \begin{cases} 0, & z < 0 \\ z/2, & 0 \le z \le 2 \\ 1, & z > 2 \end{cases} + \frac{1}{3} \begin{cases} 0, & z-1 < 0 \\ (z-1)/2, & 0 \le z-1 \le 2 \\ 1, & z-1 > 2 \end{cases} \\
&= \begin{cases} 0, & z < 0 \\ z/3, & 0 \le z \le 2 \\ 2/3, & z > 2 \end{cases} + \begin{cases} 0, & z < 1 \\ (z-1)/6, & 1 \le z \le 3 \\ 1/3, & z > 3 \end{cases} \\
&= \begin{cases} 0, & z < 0 \\
z/3, & 0 \le z < 1 \\
(3z-1)/6, & 1 \le z \le 2 \\
(z+3)/6, & 2 < z \le 3 \\
1, & z > 3.
\end{cases} \tag{6}
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 1):

When $X=0$, $XY=0$ irrespective of value of $Y$.

So, for $w\ge 0$, $P(XY\le w|X=0)=1$

Also, for $0\le w\le 2$, $P(XY\le w)=P(XY\le w|X=0)P(X=0)+P(XY\le w|X=1)P(X=1)=\frac{2}{3}+\frac{w}{6}=\frac{w+4}{6}$

In the other cases, the distribution of $XY$ is correct.

Thus, $P(XY\le w)=0$ if $w<0$

$P(XY\le w)=\frac{w+4}{6}$ if $0\le w\le 2$

$P(XY\le w)=1$ if $w>2$

Now, when $X=0$, $0\le X+Y \le 2$.

So, $P(X+Y\le w|X=0)=0$ if $w< 0$

$P(X+Y\le w|X=0)=P(Y\le w-1|X=0)=P(Y\le w)=\frac{w}{2}$ if $0 \le w\le 2$

$P(X+Y\le w|X=0)=1$ if $w>2$

When $X=1$, $1\le X+Y \le 3$.

So, $P(X+Y\le w|X=1)=0$ if $w< 1$

$P(X+Y\le w|X=1)=P(Y\le w-1|X=1)=P(Y\le w-1)=\frac{w-1}{2}$ if $1 \le w\le 3$

$P(X+Y\le w|X=1)=1$ if $w>3$

Thus, using $P(X+Y\le w)=P(X+Y\le w|X=0)P(X=0)+P(X+Y\le w|X=1)P(X=1)$ and combining the results of $P(X+Y\le w|X=0)$ and $P(X+Y\le w|X=1)$, we get,

$P(X+Y\le w)=0$ if $w\le 0$

$P(X+Y\le w)=\frac{w}{3}$ if $0<w< 1$

$P(X+Y\le w)=\frac{3w-1}{6}$ if $1\le w\le 2$

$P(X+Y\le w)=\frac{w+3}{6}$ if $2\le w\le 3$

$P(X+Y\le w)=1$ if $w>3$